A couple questions about triangle-freeness using Szemeredi's Regularity Lemma
In The Probabilistic Method by Alon and Spencer, after Szemeredi's Regularity Lemma is introduced, its application on triangle-free graphs is shown with a lemma. In the proof below, however, I have a couple questions:

I don't understand why they particularly picked an $\epsilon/4$-regular partition. When I would be solving a problem of this sort, I wouldn't know what $t$ is beforehand, so I'm not sure how they would have come up with $\epsilon/4$ – which seems very random.

Similarly, how did they come up with the $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ in the 4th bullet point? I get the general idea but not sure how they came up with this particular value. Was it just a guess that it would work out later on?


I'm asking these questions because in the exercises I have to do similar proofs like this one, so I am trying to understand how one would have come up with this solution from scratch.


I wasn't 100% sure where to post this, so let me know if MathOverflow is a better place for this question.

I think this is the correct place! MathOverflow is more for questions about research problems, while this is a question about content in a textbook.

The way I usually think about coming up with proofs like this is in a couple of steps:

Write down the structure of the proof, with all your different parameters (here $\epsilon$, $\delta$, $t$ and $T$, as well as the parameters which became $\epsilon/4$ and $\epsilon/2$). At every point where some inequality between the parameters is necessary, make note of it.

After the proof is pretty much written, go back through the inequalities we've noted down and find choices of the parameters which satisfy them.


So, to answer your question directly: the parameters were likely chosen after the rest of the proof had been written.
(Once you have more experience with these sorts of proofs, you'll have more intuition for what choices of parameters will work and what won't -- you'll probably be able to guess that the things which became $\epsilon/4$ and $\epsilon/2$, for example, ought to be linear in $\epsilon$ but less than $\epsilon$.)

I see, that makes sense.

I just have one more question – in the second bullet point, I think that the # of such edges are $k\binom{c}{2}$ because for each vertex set $V_i$ for $1 \le i \le k$, we can have a maximum of $\binom{c}{2}$ edges. How do they know that this is $\le \frac{1}{8}\epsilon n^2$?
